# Excluding "symmetric" results in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I want to query a Neo4j graph for a structure that includes two interchangeable nodes, but I don't want two unique responses for each of the "symmetric" responses.

How do I express in Cypher that two nodes are interchangeable?

### An example:

I want to look for the following structure in the graph with the following query:

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-[]->(p:Purchase)
MATCH (c:Customer)-[]->(q:Purchase)
MATCH (p)-[]->(m:Company)
MATCH (q)-[]->(m:Company)
RETURN DISTINCT c, p, q, m
```

[image: the query]

The default behavior would be for Neo4j to return the following two graphs:

[image: A symmetric graph]
[image: Another symmetric graph]

(i.e. The assignment of `p` and `q` to `Purchase1` and `Purchase2` are reversed)

How do I express that the elements `p` and `q` in my query are interchangeable, and I only need one of the above responses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent those kinds of results, you would typically have an inequality based on the node ids:

`WHERE id(p) < id(q)`

That said, you may be able to form this query a little cleaner like this (provided you want all purchases between a customer and a company with at least two purchases made from that customer to the company):

```
MATCH (c:Customer)-->(p:Purchase)-->(m:Company)
WITH c, m, collect(p) as purchases, count(p) as purchaseCount
WHERE purchaseCount >= 2
RETURN c, m, purchases
```

Comment: This "products" query was more a toy example — the main salient point is that the two responses are identical but have the same structure. The ID trick is very interesting! Will be using that. Thank you!